# How do I setup an SSH to remote into ARM using ethernet port

Tags: arm9

I am using the Xilinx Zynq 7000, on the TE0720-1 which is mounted on the TE0701-03 carrier board. I was wondering how do I set up an SSH to be able to remote into the ARM processor of the SoC to be able to transfer files and run commands.

I'm honestly not too familiar with SSH'ing just as a forewarning.

Comment: Have you checked the documentation for the operating system you're running on the chip?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams The operating system is PetaLinux, but im not sure where to start looking or what to be looking for.

Comment: Are you connected to a router?

Comment: I would ask this on superuser.com or serverfault.com, it's off topic here apart from the hardware part. You'll get a lot more SSH expertise over there.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running linux, you might want to install OpenSSH.

According to this it should already be installed: http://www.wiki.xilinx.com/Zynq+Release+14.4

Comment: Ah ok I see, and so I use the openSSH commands to remote in? So I have my laptop connected to the board using an ethernet cable. I want to be able to transfer files from my laptop to the board, however when I try to connect to it, it refuses the connection.

Comment: You will need to install the server part of OpenSSH on PetaLinux. I guess this should already have been performed. Can you check the processes that are currently active (you would do that using ps -aux or similar). Does a process related to OpenSSH (e.g. sshd) show up? Can you ping your board and are you sure that the network connection is working?

Comment: Yes, OpenSSH is showing up in the process list. However when I try to ping it, there is no response, and the packets are never received. I do not think the connection is working, or there are some security options that are preventing me from connecting, since when I try to do so, it tells me the connection was refused. Is there a way to allow this connection?

Comment: That sounds very much like a firewall issue. I am not familiar with Petalinux but I guess they might be using iptables. So maybe try this: http://serverfault.com/questions/214996/iptables-allow-ssh-access-only-nothing-else-in-or-out

Comment: if you run ifconfig on your system, does the correct IP address show up? To allow a ping, you might also need to open your firewall: http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2011/06/iptables-rules-examples/ (12 + 13)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to run an SSH server. If one is being built for you or you have binaries, place them in the file system and make sure it starts up during boot time. Otherwise you will have to cross compile OpenSSH or another server for the ARM.